# Eliminate duplicate folders in places.sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, mozilla

I have several duplicate folders in my bookmarks, because of a syncing process gone awry.  If you're not familiar, Firefox stores its bookmarks on your hard drive in a file called places.sqlite.  You can easily access this database through a tool like the [sqlite browser](https://sqlitebrowser.org).  As you can see in the [schema](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/Places/Database), the moz_bookmarks table captures a hierarchical tree structure of bookmark folders and the bookmarks that belong to them, like so:

- All Bookmarks

  - Bookmarks Toolbar
  - Bookmarks Menu

    - Cycling

      - several bookmarks. . .
    - Cycling

      - several bookmarks. . .
      - Charity Rides

        - several bookmarks. . .
    - Many other folders and bookmarks omitted. . .

In the example above, I don't want two Cycling folders.  I want to consolidate all descendants of both Cycling folders under one Cycling  folder, and then remove the empty one, so I end up with just one Cycling folder but lose no content.

As a first step, here is a query that will find all the descendants of one of the Cycling folders: 

`with cte as (
    select id, type, parent, title
    from moz_bookmarks
    where id = 2757 --id for one of the Cycling folders
    union all
    select b.id, b.type, b.parent, b.title
    from moz_bookmarks b
    join cte sub on sub.id = b.parent
)
select * from cte;`

I would need to find descendants for both folders and consolidate them.  And in reality, Cycling is not my only set of duplicate folders.  I have dozens of them, so I need code that can crank through them all in like fashion.

Comment: Please provide your table definitions, some sample data, and expected results.

Comment: @TomC see here for table definitions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/Places/Database

Comment: @TomC the following query identifies 73 duplicates: `select 
id, 
type, 
parent, 
title,
datetime(dateAdded/1000000,'unixepoch') as dateAdded, datetime(lastModified/1000000,'unixepoch') as lastModified,
guid, 
syncStatus, 
syncChangeCounter
from moz_bookmarks
where title in (select title from (
select title, count(*) as n
from moz_bookmarks
group by title
having n > 1
)) and type = 2
order by title`

Comment: Still unclear what the `children` you are referring to are. Sounds like you can already find them. Ideal way to proceed here is to add to your question create table statements, insert statements, and then indication of what should be changed/deleted. As a general tip - I would find the first row for each of your duplicate sets, modify all the other rows so they refer to the first, then delete the duplicates.

Comment: @Tom the children are the subfolders and bookmarks, all in the same table, using the parent column.  I'm thinking it would require a recursive query to get them all.  You'd have to get all the children for each dup, move them to one (it doesn't matter which), and then finally delete the dups.  All of this is a bit beyond my expertise.

Comment: Depending on the version of sqllite you are using, this is easy enough with a recursive CTE that will do exactly what you are after. If you can post some sample data - just pick 10 rows that demonstrate the issue and what your final result should be, and you should get an answer pretty quick.

Comment: I managed to create a cte that will find all the children of one folder:  `with cte as (
 select id, type, parent, title,
 datetime(dateAdded/1000000,'unixepoch') as dateAdded, datetime(lastModified/1000000,'unixepoch') as lastModified
 from moz_bookmarks
 where id = 2757
 union all
 select b.id, b.type, b.parent, b.title,
 datetime(b.dateAdded/1000000,'unixepoch') as dateAdded, datetime(b.lastModified/1000000,'unixepoch') as lastModified
 from moz_bookmarks b
 join cte sub on sub.id = b.parent
)
select * from cte; `

Comment: I still need a way to do this for each folder, consolidate the results, delete the remaining folders from this particular dup set, and then rinse and repeat for all the other dup sets.  A cursor, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

The CTE in your comment is close, but you are not saving the anchor point. To answer your question about cursors, NO, NEVER! Any time you think about using a cursor you are almost certainly wrong. (ok there are occasions, but they really are for special purposes, not simple database updates).

I'm still not clear about the data and what you want to do, but this version of the CTE will find all rows that have no parent (parent is null), and then all its children. It will also save the top level id as the anchor so that you can use it to roll the other ones up.

I'm sure this is not 100% of what you need, but it should give a good idea that you can use.

You can then save that into a temporary table, and use it as the basis of whatever you need to do - set the parent for any rows to the top level parent, set min createddate or max modified date, or delete the rows completely.

Do it all set based rather than trying to loop through anything using a cursor.

This would be your CTE with the anchor (topID saved):

```
with cte as ( 
    -- Find all the rows that are top level
    select id as TopID, type, id, null as parent, title, 
        datetime(dateAdded/1000000,'unixepoch') as dateAdded, 
        datetime(lastModified/1000000,'unixepoch') as lastModified 
    from moz_bookmarks 
    where parent is null  
union all 
    select cte.TopID, b.type, b.id, b.parent, b.title, 
        datetime(b.dateAdded/1000000,'unixepoch') as dateAdded, 
        datetime(b.lastModified/1000000,'unixepoch') as lastModified 
    from moz_bookmarks b 
    join cte sub on sub.id = b.parent
) 
select * from cte;
```

Comment: I have edited my question to try and make it more clear.  Regarding cursors, I think they could work for a personal bookmarks project like this with a few thousand rows, but I'd be happy to learn a superior set-based solution.